# Why does the view auto animate?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in a `UIViewController` that changes the height of the view when the keyboard opens.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Subscribe to keyboard events.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardHeight = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.height

    //  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.view.frame.size.height -= keyboardHeight
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    //  }
}
```

I notice that the view animates even without `UIView.animateWithDuration`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification is send out as part of an animation block. If you extract the information from the notification related to the animation, you can have other views animate alongside with it. In your case, all the changes to any view you make between `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardDidShow` are going to be animated as part of that keyboard-animation.